# pythonからC関数呼び出しの際に構造体アドレス渡しの方法

Tags: python, c, ポインタ, dll

PythonでC DLLのラッパーを作ろうとしています。
C DLLのAPIの中には構造体のポインタアドレスを引数としているものがあり、
クライアント（C DLLを使う側）が構造体の実態を作り、
そのアドレスをC DLLのAPI引数として呼び出す必要があります。
Pythonで構造体の実態を作り、
またそのアドレスを関数に渡す方法を教えてください。

現在、Pythonからctypesライブラリを使用してWinDLL関数でC DLLの関数呼び出しを行うことはできました。
また、longなどのポインタアドレスを渡す方法も理解できました。

理解できていないのは構造体のアドレス渡しです。
例えば以下のようなC DLL関数をpythonから呼び出し方法についてご教授いただけると幸いです。

**dll header**

```
typedef struct {
   char DeviceTypeFCC[4];
   int nDeviceType;
   long CID;
   BOOL bIsConnected;
   long UCID;
   long rsv[3];
   char data[992];
} DEVICEINFO;

int CreateDeviceHandle(const DEVICEINFO* pInfo,void* phDevice);
```

Comment: [pywin32 - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) とか [pywin32-ctypes - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32-ctypes/) あるいは [cffi - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/cffi/) のソースコードや使い方等を調べてみれば良いのでは？ [pywin32によりPythonからWin32 APIにアクセスする](https://self-development.info/pywin32%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8Apython%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89win32-api%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/), [PythonによるWindowsメッセージフック・前編](https://qiita.com/Aroe/items/502cc5665ae17db8654a), [Pass objects between libraries in Python cffi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54986536/9014308)

Answer (score 4):

構造体のポインターを利用する方法
(手元の環境は Ubuntuなので, Windowsとは多少 利用方法(ctypes API)が異なるかも)

```py
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library

class FILE(ctypes.Structure):
    pass   # 必要に応じてメンバーを記述

FILE_p = ctypes.POINTER(FILE)

libc = ctypes.CDLL(find_library('c'), use_errno=True)
cstdout = FILE_p.in_dll(libc, 'stdout')

# C言語関数(API) setbuf
csetbuf = libc.setbuf
csetbuf.argtypes = (FILE_p, ctypes.c_char_p)
csetbuf.restype = None

# C言語関数(API) fflush
cfflush = libc.fflush
cfflush.restype = ctypes.c_int

# 関数(API)呼び出し
cfflush(cstdout)
csetbuf(cstdout, None)
```

構造体メンバーの利用方法はドキュメントを参照するとよいでしょう
参考: docs.python.org [構造体と共用体](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions)

```py
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> class POINT(Structure):
...     _fields_ = [("x", c_int),
...                 ("y", c_int)]
...
>>> point = POINT(10, 20)
>>> print(point.x, point.y)
10 20
```

---

**更新 (コメントから, 追加質問)**

> C APIの中で作られた構造体のアドレスをPython側で受け取る

C言語の `func`関数の実体

```c
typedef struct pos {
    int x,y;
}
pos_st;

pos_st c_val = {123,456};

int
func(pos_st **p)
{
    *p = &c_val;
    return 0;
}
```

呼び出し側の Python
`CFUNCTYPE` についてはドキュメント参考のこと (https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/ctypes.html)

```py
import ctypes as ct

class POS(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", ct.c_int),
                ("y", ct.c_int)]

pos_ptr = ct.POINTER(ct.POINTER(POS))
point = POS(10, 20)   # dummy
ppoint = ct.pointer(point)

func = ct.CFUNCTYPE(ct.c_int, pos_ptr)(func)   # func取り出し (環境に依る)
r = func(ppoint)
print(f'result: {r:#x}')
# result: 0x0

newpoint = ppoint.contents
print(newpoint.x, newpoint.y)
# 123 456
```

Comment: Python側で作られた構造体のアドレスを渡す方法について理解・実装できました。
追加の質問をさせてください。
C APIの中で作られた構造体のアドレスをPython側で受け取る必要があるのですが、その書き方についてもご教授いただけると幸いです。
例えばIMAGE構造体のポインタのアドレスを知りたいです。
IMAGE* image_p = nullptr;
func(&image_p);

Comment: 回答では, `libc`から`stdout`をエクスポートされた値を取得し, 使用しています
`cstdout = FILE_p.in_dll(libc, 'stdout')` (それが `FILE`構造体のポインター)。
エクスポートされた構造体ポインターでないなら, あとは関数の戻り値くらいだろうけど そちらも(回答のように) `func.restype = FILE_p` のように指定し, 呼び出すだけです

Comment: ありがとうございます。上手く伝えられず申し訳ありません。
引数にダブルポインタが指定されている関数があり、スタックしております。